# Flutter: Determining the speed of a vehicle using GPS

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to monitor the speed the of device(mobile,tablet,..) like google maps where they shows the speed of vehicle moving with almost exact speed with the delay of fractions of second. if it is possible please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can measure the speed by using [`geolocator`](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin. It provides you `Position` object and you can call `speed` on it. Example:

```dart
Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((position) {
  double speedMps = position.speed; // This is your speed
});
```

---

(Optional) You can also provide location settings to it. For example:

```dart
var androidSettings = AndroidSettings(
  // Change parameters to your liking.
);
var iosSettings = AppleSettings(
  // Change parameters to your liking. 
);
var settings = Platform.isIOS ? iosSettings : androidSettings;
Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: settings).listen((position) {
  double speedMps = position.speed;
});
```

Comment: it didnt work, can you give me more context or an example to follow? I would highly appreciate it, Thanks in advance

Comment: does this work for mobile websites also? As per docs "The speed at which the devices is traveling in meters per second over ground.
The speed is not available on all devices. In these cases the value is 0.0." but I didn't find any doc mentioning the devices and platforms supported.

Answer (score 2):

This is the currently working implementation...

```
 Geolocator.getPositionStream(
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
        intervalDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        distanceFilter: 2,
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation)
    .listen((position) {
  var speedInMps =
      position.speed.toStringAsPrecision(2); // this is your speed
  print(speedInMps);
```

Comment: Why is it giving non zero speed even at rest ?

Comment: @abdullah may be due to accuracy limitation which makes it look like the device is moving.

Comment: Force the Android Location Manager it's not recommended. The Fused Location Provider is a better approach in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed in km:

speedInKm = speedInMps * 3.6;

---

How to convert m/s to km/h ?

### **Method 1 (deduction method):**

Looking at the whole thing logically, to convert m/s to km/h, divide meters by 1000 and then multiply the result by 3600.

For example, to convert 40 m/s to km/h:

- Step 1: 40 m/1000 = 0.04 km
- Step 2: 0.04 km * 3600 = 144
- Result: 40 m/s = 144 km/h

Why do we do these actions and not others? Because first we need to convert meters to kilometers. To do this, we have to divide them by 1,000, because 1 m = 0.001 km. At this stage, we will get the result in kilometers per second. To get the result in kilometers per hour, we must additionally multiply the whole number by 3600, because 1 hour = 3600 seconds.

### **Method 2 (faster):**

A shorter way is to multiply m/s times 3.6 because 1 m/s = 3.6 km/h.

Example: 12 m/s * 3.6 = 43.2 km/h.

### **Convert km/h to m/s**

To quickly convert km/h to m/s, just divide it by 3.6.

Example: 90 km/h / 3.6 = 25 m/s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).