# Can i calculate the current speed using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a flutter application and using Google maps API, i know that i can get acceleration through accelerometer, But is there any way that can i calculate the instantaneous speed?  Or somehow get it from the Maps API?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to calculate the speed yourself, just use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), get the speed value from a returned Position.

Comment: can you give me more details please, i'm new to flutter and mobile development

Comment: Check this question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437692/flutter-determining-the-speed-of-a-vehicle-using-gps

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the simple formula you can use to calculate the speed
//Time, Distance, Pace, Speed formulas and relationships

time = pace × distance
//time = pace time per unit distance × distance
distance = time / pace
distance = time / pace time per unit distance
pace = time / distance
//pace time per unit distance = time / distance
speed = distance / time
speed distance per unit time = distance / time
```